# Change button image after clicking it

Tags: c#, winforms

i have picturebox with picture cb.

```
PBr1_1.Image = new Bitmap(@"Logos\\Images\\cb.png");
```

I'd like to change image to cg.png and do some action when i click this image. I was trying something like that but without success:

```
private void PBr1_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
   if (PBr1_1.Image.ToString() == "cb.png")
          {
             PBr1_1.Image = new Bitmap(@"Logos\\Images\\cg.png");
            // Do some stuff.
          }
}
```

And then do the same when i click image with cb. To visualise this cb is black circle button image, and cg is green one.

How can i do this?

Comment: You could use the `Tag` property of the control instead of ToString-ing the image, which probably doesn't return what you want.

Comment: But how to get this information using Tag property?  This didn't work:       MessageBox.Show(PBr1_1.Image.Tag.ToString()); and this also
MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(PBr1_1.Image.Tag));

Comment: You can set the `Tag` property to be anything you want. And so you can get whatever you set `Tag` to be. Did you read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag.aspx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jason is right, you should use some kind of temporary storage to save your current bitmap.
The Tag property is useful in this kind of situations. Here a sample code: (Without error handling)

somewhere in your load event

```
PBr1.Tag = "cb.png";`
PBr1_1.Image = new Bitmap(Path.Combine("Logos\\Images", PBr1.Tag.ToString());
```

and then in button click

```
private void PBr1_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{     
   string imgPath = "Logos\\Images";
   PBr1_1.Image.Dispose();
   PBr1_1.Tag = (PBr1_1.Tag == "cb.png" ? "cg.png") : "cb.png") ; 
   Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(Path.Combine(imgPath, PBr1.Tag.ToString());
   PBr1_1.Image = bm; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that "PBr1_1.Image.ToString()" really returns only the image name?
Maybe you should check this by writing PBr1_1.Image.ToString() to console or something like that

Comment: No it's not -it returns System.Drawing.Bitmap, but this was one of my try to do this :)

Comment: Then save the image paths to string variables and create the images like that: string myImg="PATH_TO_IMAGE"
System.Drawing.Image foo=System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(myImg);